# Unable to extract fields from TCP dump pcap file using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I am using scapy 2.2.3 library with python. I can get the summary of pcap file using summary method but it is not in friendly format. I want to get the fields like sequence number. ack number etc. 
I was following [this](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#reading-pcap-files) documentation. Can anyone point me to the right direction. i am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to extract certain fields you can index the packet via the layer plus any member variables on the layer (fields).

Example

```
from scapy.all import *
a=rdpcap("mycapture.pcap")
print(a[0][IP].dst)
print(a[0][IP].src)
```

The above example assumes the first packet in the capture is an IP packet and will print out the destination and source IP addresses which are fields on that layer of the packet.